# sending mail in ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a simple page with 3 textbox and a button like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" required >
<input type="text" ng-model="city" required >
<input type="text" ng-model="country" required >



<button class="button button-block button-royal ExploreBtn" ng-click="sendMail();">
Send mail               
</button>
```

Help me , How to send mail with value in first text-field as subject and other two as body in angular js/ionic.

Comment: You need backend for this. Can't do it with just JS.

Comment: Indeed, you need a SMTP Server to send emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically the comments to your question are correct - you can't do this purely in JavaScript, you need to use a backend service for it.

Now, what you would do in your `sendMail` function is call the service by using Angulars'  `$http` service. You can learn more about $http service from the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

The call would, for example look like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://your.server.com/sendmail.php',
    data: { mailTo: 'me@gmail.com', msg: 'hello!' }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    alert("msg sent!");
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert("error with sending a msg");
});
```

Here you have two important parts:

- `url` - where is your service (which will finally send the email) located
- `data` - what are you sending to this service endpoint

In my example I've put the service url to be `sendmail.php` which, in end, would be written in PHP. I have to stress out that your backend service can be written in any server-side language you're familiar with (if you'll research this topic further make sure you read about the [RESTful services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)).

For the sake of this example, the PHP script (*unsecured and just for reference*) which uses the [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to send an email would look something like this:

```
<?php

$to = $_POST["emailTo"];
$msg = $_POST["msg"];

mail($to, "Some test subject", $msg);

?>
```

Hope this helps clear the confusion.

Comment: hi.. I have zero knowledge in php. Can you help me how to change "msg" value dynamically according to text-box

Comment: Well, basically this has nothing to do with PHP. Since you're sending the message from Ionic (Angular) application you would add another input box with the `msg` model like: `<input type="text" ng-model="msg" required >` and then you would use it in the ajax call like this: `data: { mailTo: 'me@gmail.com', msg: $scope.msg }`

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Accepting it :)

Comment: No problem, glad that I helped. Wish you good luck with this project!